# Getting the arguments of the last invoked command in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to get the argument portion of the previous command. `$^` seems to return just the command and not the args. `Get-History -count 1` returns the last full command including the command and the args. I could just .Replace the first instance, but I am not sure if it is correct.

Scenario is that sometimes I want to do something like this. Let's assume that $* are the args to the last command:

```
dir \\share\files\myfile.exe
copy $* c:\windows\system32
```

Any ideas how to get the last args correctly?

UPDATE: finished my method for doing this.

```
function Get-LastArgs
{
    $lastHistory = (Get-History -count 1)
    $lastCommand = $lastHistory.CommandLine   
    $errors = [System.Management.Automation.PSParseError[]] @()

    [System.Management.Automation.PsParser]::Tokenize($lastCommand, [ref] $errors) | ? {$_.type -eq "commandargument"} | select -last 1 -expand content    
 }
```

Now I can just do:

```
dir \\share\files\myfile.exe
copy (Get-LastArgs) c:\windows\system32
```

To reduce typing, I did

```
set-alias $* Get-LastArgs
```

so now I still have to do

```
copy ($*) c:\windows\system32
```

if anybody has any ideas for making this better please let me know.

Comment: +1 interesting question. if you don't get a satisfactory answer out of this, consider suggestion such a feature on connect.microsoft.com/powershell

Comment: with PSReadLine, Alt+. yanks the last argument. If you precede it with a digital argument, it yanks it. So Alt+0 Alt+. will yank the first argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to get the last args in this fashion without parsing the history item itself, and this is no trivial matter. The reason is that the "last arguments" may not be what you think they are after you take splatting, pipelines, nested subexpressions, named and unnammed arguments/parameters into the equasion. In powershell v2 there is a parser available for tokenizing commands and expressions, but I'm not sure you want to go that route.

```
ps> $psparser::Tokenize("dir foo", [ref]$null) | ? {
    $_.type -eq "commandargument" } | select -last 1 -expand content
foo
```

Answer (score 18):

For the last argument (not all!) in the interactive hosts like Console and ISE it is the automatic variable `$$`.

Help

```
man about_Automatic_Variables
```

gets

```
$$
Contains the last token in the last line received by the session.
```

Other hosts may or may not implement this feature (as well as the `$^` variable).

Comment: I inadvertently discovered that myself which can be helpful in some cases, but I really would love all arguments! Guess I will have to put in a feature request.

Comment: Of course, if you find this useful, submit the request. Personally, I am sceptic about that sort of variables, see the link. But I can change my mind if there are actually useful applications.
https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/509802/remove-automatic-variables-and

Comment: it's a pity it doesn't expand to the actual argument like Ctrl + . does